# Is there a way to generate N integer numbers increasingly and the sum of them equals to M?

Tags: python

Is there a way to generate N integer numbers increasingly and the sum of them equals to M?

for example:

N = 4
M = 10
output: 1 , 2 , 3 , 4

1+2+3+4 = M = 10 and they are growing

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this, but you might have issues in some edge cases. But if N and M exist, this should find it.

```
k = ((m - np.sum( np.arange(n-1) )) // n)
np.arange(k,k + n)
```

Comment: Hi, This code is generating negative numbers, and they must be only integers too. example: N = 5 and M = 100. output: 10 + 15 + 20 + 25 + 30 = 100 = M

Comment: if n = 5 and m = 100, shouldn't the list be [18, 19, 20, 21, 22] ?, the code above should return this

Comment: Yes, [18, 19, 20, 21, 22]  could be the answer too.

Answer (score 0):

Math can help you here.

If N is odd, then divide your M by N to get the middle number. From there, work our the first (N-1)/2 and then the next (N-1)/2 numbers.

If N is even, apply the same logic, except that your next numbers are 0.5 and -0.5 away from your average. From there you can work the first (N-2)/2 and the next (N-2)/2 numbers.